# Magento Module config.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm learning Magento extension developing, Already understand enough to start with PHP OOP, MVC and Zend framework.

Now i need to understand the concept of config.xml file in the /etc folder in my module, Already found table explain each entry like what is ,, .. etc.

But i need to understand in more details how it works.

An example of what in my mind is to add for example (new payment method) it will be easier to explain with example.

Already created my controllers, models, blocks .. etc folders.

Anybody can explain it in details or provide me with resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this quite useful as a starting point

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

I'm still learning module development but the module works